# Probability question on guessing if number is higher , is it possible to even solve?

Tags: probability

A and B are playing a game. A randomly chooses two rational numbers between 0 and 1, both included. He keeps them hidden in two chits. B chooses any of them and guesses if the number he sees is the higher of the two. He wins if he guesses correctly. Is it possible for B to win more than half of the games that he plays with A? If yes, what is the probability?

My attempt was that the probability that B gets the higher number is higher is half , and prob that he guesses right that the given number is higher, too is half . So when the prev 2 cases overlap, he actually gets higher and guesses higher. But chances of this happening is extremely low , so i think its impossible for B to win more than half of the games.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  And for clarity.  How is $A$ choosing the numbers?  Is he choosing them uniformly at random or is he specifically choosing them to mislead $B$?  See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9037/how-is-it-that-you-can-guess-if-one-of-a-pair-of-random-numbers-is-larger-with) for the random case (though they are a little vague about what uniform distribution they are talking about.  The discussion works better if you have a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.)